# My Google App Script takes too long to end. Need to do it faster

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Issue:-** My script usually takes 5 minutes on an average. Can we change anything in the code to transfer the data quicker?

**What it does?**

- It transfers the fresh data populated in the source sheet into the repository in the destination sheet. The source sheet data is refreshed every day, but in the destination sheet, data transferred gets appended day by day.

***Here is the script:***

```
function UploadRepository() { 
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SourceSheet"); 
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("DestinationSheet"); 
  var currDate = new Date(); 
  var editedDate = new Date(currDate - 86400000); 
  var insert = sheet1.getSheetByName("SourceSheetName"); 
  var archive = sheet2.getSheetByName("DestinationSheetName"); 
  var insertData = insert.getRange(2, 1, (sheet1.getRange('A:A').getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow()), 28); 
  for (row = 2; row <= insertData.getNumRows(); row++) { 
    var data = insert.getRange(row, 1, 1, 28).getValues(); 
    if (data[0][0] < currDate && data[0][0] > editedDate) { 
      archive.getRange((archive.getLastRow() + 1), 1, 1, 28).setValues(data).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the code formatting in the question? It is currently unreadable. See [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). There is also a preview feature, so you can check everything before saving your changes.

Comment: [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this instead of your `for` loop?

#### Code:

```
insertData = insertData.getValues().map(function(row){
  if(row[0] < currDate && row[0] > editedDate) 
    return row;
}).filter(Boolean);

archive.getRange(archive.getLastRow() + 1, 1, insertData.length, insertData[0].length).setValues(insertData).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

#### Behavior:

- filter your `insertData` values meeting the `if` condition, then setting the value of the `archive` sheet at once instead of doing it one by one in a loop.

#### Difference in runtime:

#### 10 Rows:

[image: 10]

#### 50 Rows:

[image: 50]

#### 100 Rows:

[image: 100]

#### Note:

- I didn't do multiple executions per test to get an average runtime since the difference is so big, a few milliseconds doesn't even matter.